# use CreateUserWizard control to create records in your own database

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, createuserwizard

When dragging a CreateUserWizard control into the ASP.NET application, the "Create user" button uses the default database: "aspnetdb" to insert or create the new user.

I want to use the CreateUserWizard control of ASP.NET to create my own users (from my own database), but I cannot do so, because I cannot access the click event of the submit button whose text is "Create user" (that is a part of the CreateUserWizard control)

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a custom membership provider and override CreateUser.

- [How to: Implement a Custom
  Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)
- [Writing A Custom Membership Provider
  for your ASP.NET 2.0 Web Site](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/1954)
- [Building Custom Providers for
  ASP.NET 2.0 Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx)

Comment: Please can you provide me with an additional clue... I added my own answer to clarify my situation.